# Getting a list of registered servers thru powershell to .csv

Tags: powershell, ssms, sql-server-2008

How to get the list of registered servers from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) thru powershell to .csv, I figured how to register but how to export the registered servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try :

```
Get-ChildItem 'SQLSERVER:\SQLRegistration' -Recurse
```

---

Edited

To see all attributes :

```
Get-ChildItem 'SQLSERVER:\SQLRegistration' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_ -is [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServer]} | fl *
```

`Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServer` comes from :

```
Get-ChildItem 'SQLSERVER:\SQLRegistration' -Recurse | Get-Member
```

To export those you need in a csv file :

```
Get-ChildItem 'SQLSERVER:\SQLRegistration' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_ -is [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServer]} | select servername,servertype | Export-Csv C:\temp\sql.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: ok i got all the list of databases so how do i export this to .csv?